# How to manage parameters with different length in R

Tags: r

I have to data sets (80211 and mine) as follows: each file has one column of data.

```
80211
    1
    2 
    3
    4
    5

mine
    1
    2
    3
```

I need to read these two files and plot the cdf with ggplot2 but it says that the length of parameters are different.

The code is here.

```
library(ggplot2)
data1 <- read.csv('80211')
data2 <- read.csv('mine')

df <- data.frame(x = c(data1, data2), ggg=factor(rep(1:2, c(5,3))))
ggplot(df, aes(x, colour = ggg)) + 
stat_ecdf()+
scale_colour_hue(name="my legend", labels=c('80211','mine'))
```

Comment: x = c(data1[1:length(data2)], data2), you have to have a pair of coordinates to plot a point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#Here this seems to work:
require(ggplot2)
data1 <- 1:5
data2 <- 1:3

df <- data.frame(x = c(data1, data2), ggg=factor(rep(1:2, c(5,3))))
ggplot(df, aes(x, colour = ggg)) + 
  stat_ecdf()+
  scale_colour_hue(name="my legend", labels=c('80211','mine'))
```

Comment: Ok. this is exactly my code. I think I have problem in ready my files. I need to read my files and I use read.table for doing that but I think there is something wrong because I got the error.